# Is there a page layout user control where I can add my own controls on it?

Tags: c#, user-controls

I am looking for a user control that portrays a page (preferably A4). On that page the user should be able to add other user controls (labels, charts,...), move and resize them. Additionally it would be great if there was a way to print the page in the end.

Does someone of you maybe know where I can find a user control that has such a functionality? I was searching for hours but I am just not able to find anything like that.